# How is base64 encoded data stored in .Net strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, base64, utf-16

Pretty basic question with probably a pretty basic answer that i just couldn't wrap my head around.

In .Net, if I encode my byte[] using base64, i get a string reference in return. But strings in .Net are UTF-16 encoded. So how exactly is it actually stored/represented?

Comment: Not quite sure what is your actual question.... The only purpose of base64 encoding - is to get string containing only ASCII characters, so it has nothing to do with .NET encoding/respresentation of strings. It should be considered only as some function byte[] -> string, so you're just getting a string and it is stored as in .NET as usual utf-16 encoded data.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) help? Base64 is just an encoding that represents binary data in ASCII form. And UTF-16 is a superset of ASCII (i.e., everything that can be represented in ASCII is representable in UTF-16 in the same way). So ASCII text can easily be stored in .NET strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But strings in .Net are UTF-16 encoded. So how exactly is it actually stored/represented?

You've already answered your own question: since strings in .NET are stored as UTF16, that is *exactly* how the base64 text is stored/represented.

Encoding binary data as base64 simply trades one representation problem for another: straight binary data is broken into a stream of 6-bit values, which are in turn represented by a set of 64 different characters. Now that the data is represented by characters, you need to decide how to represent the *characters*.

But in-memory, .NET uses UTF16. So the decision is already made for you: the characters of the base64 string value are represented using UTF16.

Now, if you want to save those characters, or send them over a network, or otherwise let them leave the environment of .NET, you will have to re-encode them to suit your needs. At the very least, even if you're just sending them as UTF16, .NET will (barring unsafe code) require you to pass them through some object (e.g. `StreamWriter`, `Encoding`, etc.) that will transform the .NET string to the necessary bytes, and of course if you need the text in some other encoding, you'll have to specify that as well (e.g. by using the appropriate `Encoding` object).

For example, let's say I have the string `"Hello"` and I want to encode this as base64 (just ignore that if I really only had text data, I'd just encode it as a string directly :) ). The first thing I need to do is decide what text encoding to use for the original string, since base64 only encodes binary data. I pick ASCII: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello")` yields the array `{ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 }`.

Now that I have an array of bytes, I can encode as base64: `Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[] { 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 })` yields the string value of `"SGVsbG8="` (expressed as a C# literal…of course the double-quotes are part of the literal syntax, not the string itself).

So your question comes down to, how is that string represented in memory? Well, it's represented as UTF16, just as you'd expect. And that looks like this array of bytes:

```
{ 83, 0, 71, 0, 86, 0, 115, 0, 98, 0, 71, 0, 56, 0, 61, 0 };
```

That is exactly how the string `"Hello"`, encoded as ASCII and then as base64, would be stored/represented in-memory using a .NET string value. That's the numerical byte values that represent the UTF16-encoded text that the string literal `"SGVsbG8="` is.

Comment: So if I then send the string "SGVsbG8=" to a soap client what i'm actually sending is a UTF-16 encoded string. And the client will in turn store it as such. It's up to the developer to tell the code that the bytes that represent this string are actually base64 encoded and that it should be decoded.

Comment: _"if I then send...to a soap client what i'm actually sending is a UTF-16 encoded string"_ -- No, not necessarily. It depends on what encoding is being used for the communication. It's UTF16 in memory, but that's all you can say, and you can only say that because that's always what .NET uses. Any valid text encoding could be used to then transmit that string to some remote process, like a SOAP client. When the client receives the data, it will then (presumably) decode the bytes it receives back to whatever _its_ in-memory representation of a string is, and then decode the base64 from that.